# How to combine previously saved graphs in R

Tags: r, graph

I have written this code that plots a ROC curve for 16 different countries and saves them as a pdf. I would now would like to combine them into one plot in the last step and unfortunately cannot get it to work.

This is my code. I am not sure if I should instead save the graphs as a vector? The error message then reads "object 'roc_au' not found" (roc curve for Australia) when trying to combine them into one. Help is much appreciated - thank you!!

```
pdf(paste0('roc_',country,'.pdf'))
  plot(
    performance(rent.preds, "tpr", "fpr"),
    lwd = 2,
    lty = 2,
    col = "red",
    xlab = "False Positives Rate",
    ylab = "True Positive Rate",
    main = paste0(toupper(country), ""),
    sub = paste0("Area under ROC curve =", colAUC),
    cex.sub = 0.7
  )
  abline(
    a = 0,
    b = 1,
    lwd = 3,
    lty = 3,
    col = "grey"
  )
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  What do you want for the final result, one graph with all the results overlapping, or a document containing 16 separate graphs?

Comment: Apologies - I am trying to create a document / graph that combines the 16 separate graphs (but not overlaps them)

Comment: Are you trying to read in one of the PDFs into a local variable? If so, how are you doing that? Would it not be better to merge them into one plot _when plotting them_? Base-only can be done using `layout(..)` or `par(new=TRUE)`, but it might be much easier using the `patchwork` package (it supports base graphics and grid/ggplot2).

Comment: How would I merge them into one plot when plotting them? The problem is that I cannot access the separate plots that I have exported when trying later to use the layout or patchwork package, I always get notified that 'the object is not found.'

Comment: Putting 16 plots on one page could be a bit much.  If you want multiple pages, the easiest way is to make an R Markdown document.  Just put one page of graphics in one code chunk (maybe multiple plots, using @r2evans' excellent answer to combine them).  You'll probably want to specify a larger size than the default.

Comment: Hannah, I don't know what `performance` is returning, but another option may be to take its returned data and send to `ggplot()` and use `facet_*` to get your 16 groups on one plot. According to the docs, `ggplot2` is supported, so you may benefit from exploring that side.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to combine plots. I'll work on three `mtcars` scatter plots for demo.

## Base R only

```r
(mtx <- matrix(c(1:3, 0), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    3    0
layout(mtx)
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))
# abline or any other plot-addition can go here
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 6))
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 8))
```

The original `mtx` defines the order of plots. You can define the `widths=` and `heights=` if you need non-uniform sizing of plots. A `0` is a placeholder, no plot is put into that space. Depending on your preferences and the aspects of your plots, you may want to change `par(mar=...)` to reduce the blank space around plots. Note, though, that doing different margins for different plots will likely make the "box" not align (in fact, having different scales can do that, too).

[image: base-R combined plots]

You can have a plot span multiple cells in the matrix, as in

```r
(mtx <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    3
```

[image: base R plot with multi-cell plots]

It is possible to get even more fine-grain control over placement using `par(fig=.., new=TRUE)`, such as

```r
par(fig=c(0, 0.7, 0, 0.7), bg = "white")
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))
par(fig=c(0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.8), new = TRUE)
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 6))
```

[image: base R plot with par fig/new]

(Obviously with this much control comes much responsibility ...)

## `patchwork`

This package is perhaps better-known for combining grid-based (including `ggplot2`), but it can join base graphics as well if the `gridGraphics` package is also installed.

(To be fair, I don't know why I needed to wrap every single base plot in `wrap_elements`, perhaps somebody more knowledgeable will advise a better way.)

```r
library(patchwork)
wrap_elements(NULL, ~ plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))) + 
  wrap_elements(NULL, ~ plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 6))) + 
  wrap_elements(NULL, ~ plot(mpg ~ disp, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 8))) + plot_layout(ncol=2)
```

[image: patchwork-combined plots]

The `patchwork` package allows significant control including overlaps/insets, etc.